# Existence of a matrix whose power series converges to a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, power-series

Given a real symmetric matrix $A$, how do I prove whether a series of the form $\sum_{i=0}^\infty B^i =A$ for some matrix $B$ exists? If it exists, how do I find such a matrix $B$?

Comment: Hint: could you do it if $A$ is diagonal? What are nice properties of symmetric matrices for the non-diagonal case.

Comment: Is it $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} A^{i}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie no, a separate matrix $B$

Comment: @RishiSonthalia ooh! It'd be like a power series in the real number case? And for symmetric matrices I can diagonalize it! Is that the right direction?

Comment: Ah, @JeanMarie did you mean the summation index? I just fixed that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $B$ satisfies the condition $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty B^i=A$$
Observe that $$AB=BA=\sum_{i=0}^\infty B^{i+1}= A-I$$Then $$(I-B)A=A(I-B)= I$$ Therefore $A$ must be invertible and $$B=I-A^{-1}$$ The symmetry and the real valued entries are not essential.

In order to complete the proof we need the convergence of the series $\sum_iB^i.$ Such series is convergent iff the eigenvalues of $B$ have absolute values strictly less than $1.$ Therefore the absolute values of $I-A^{-1}$ should satisfy that property, i.e. the eigenvalues of $A$ fulfill $$ |1-\lambda|<|\lambda|$$ which means their real parts are greater than $1/2.$

Summarizing the solution exists if and only if the real parts of eigenvalues of $A$ are greater than $1/2.$ In particular $A$ is invertible and $B=I-A^{-1}.$

**Remark** The explanation that the power series $\sum B^i$ is convergent iff the eigenvalues of $B$ have absolute values less than $1$ is based on the Jordan form of the matrix $B.$ It suffices to prove convergence for every block of the matrix $B.$ Such block is of the form $\lambda I+S,$ where $S$ is the matrix with entries $1$ on the upper diagonal and $0$ otherwise. Then $$(\lambda I+S)^i =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{i\choose k}\lambda^{i-k}S^k,$$ where $n$ denotes the dimension of the block. The infinite sum terminates as $S^n=0.$ Therefore the series $$\sum (\lambda I+S)^i$$ is convergent iff $|\lambda|<1.$

Comment: An intermediate step with finite sums looks compulsory. Properties of finite sums do not extend naturally to (infinite) series.

Comment: You also need $\|I-A^{-1}\| <1$

Comment: Is this solution unique or is it just one convenient construction of a solution?

Comment: The solution is unique, which follows from the first part of the answer.

Comment: I had a follow-up question that I suddenly forgot about :(. I'll try RishiSonthalia's hint first and come back to this. 
 Thanks @RyszardSzwarc